# Difference between int cast and int& cast

Tags: c++

```
Float a;
int i=(Int) a;
Int& j=(Int &) a;
```

Can't type with extensive details using my phone.
Can anyone tell thx

Update: 
Not quite you Lot expected. Since Google was completely banned here in China.  I can barely login using laptop.  Always popping message like require third party JavaScript.  typing Is hard. so that's it and to the one claims this a simple reference,  incomplete i think. It's more complicated than that

Update:
Best just change title. Seems casting to different type could cause problems. So what's different between the two processes of different typecast.

Last update: 
Experimented, why i and j are different. Don't vow down if you can't answer yourself

Comment: First casts to `int`, second casts to a reference to `int`

Comment: *"Can't type with extensive details using my phone."*  Why do you need to type on your phone? Are you sitting an exam right now?

Comment: Neither `Float` nor `Int` are things in C++.

Comment: The device you are using is irrelevant to us. Stack Overflow has its guidelines and you must follow them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should static\_cast, dynamic\_cast, const\_cast and reinterpret\_cast be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: Tell what? `int` and `int&` are totally different things. It is not really possible to post a tutorial about references here. Perhaps you should start with a good C++ book.

Answer (score -2):

(int) will cast the float value to sizeof(int) byte integer value <= float value

(int &) will convert the float value to a one byte refrence